# Sorting two different php loops that generate a single html listing

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using ACF plugin in Wordpress I created a checkbox field which return the ID of each selected values. I then echo the image of each selected values through `wp_get_attachment_image`.

I also created a text field for dynamic input of text [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjUHt.png) which then becomes [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieI3r.png)

Here is a piece of my code :

```
<?php $values_caract = get_field('picto_statique_Caract');
                            if( !empty($values_caract) ): ?>
                                <div class="icon-list">
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php foreach($values_caract as $value_caract): ?>
                                            <li><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $value_caract, 'full' );?></li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        <?php if( get_field('ip3x') ): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="picto">
                                                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 3145, 'full' );?>
                                                    <div class="text-ip3x">
                                                        <?php the_field('ip3x'); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if( get_field('ip4x') ): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="picto">
                                                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 3158, 'full' );?>
                                                    <div class="text-ip3x">
                                                        <?php the_field('ip4x'); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
     </ul>
     </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```

My issue is that this generate a list of images which I cannot sort because the foreach loop for static images and the if condition for dynamic images are two different loops.
Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Instead of displaying the images, save them to an array. Then after the loop, all your images will be in one array that you can sort before looping through it to display the images.

Comment: Could you please be more explicit and give some example code ?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to be more explicit, its quite simple... instead of echoing the image, add it to an array. You don't say how the images should be sorted, so sort them as required in the array. Then put your display code inside a loop looping through the array of images.